# mysql repeated query

Tags: mysql

I don't want it to repeat in the query you see in the example, I want it to show only one

```
SELECT bulten.id,group_concat(spor.sonuc)as result,count(spor.sonuc)as total FROM bulten 
INNER JOIN spor on bulten.ms1=spor.ms1 AND bulten.lig=spor.lig
group by bulten.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d277a/1

Comment: What is "it" you don't want to repeat?

Comment: bulten table There are 3 units of 1.10 and GER,repeats 3 times, 
I want it to repeat once

Comment: DISTINCT bulten.ms1 
unfortunately it doesn't happen

Comment: You have inserted this combination 3 times into the table "bulten", review your fiddle...

Comment: Your actual issue is, that your database is not normalized and you're using the wrong fields for referencing tables. If your database is in 3NF and you follow its rules, your problem will dissolve automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to groupp the bulten table before joining

```
SELECT bulten.id,group_concat(spor.sonuc)as result,count(spor.sonuc)as total 
FROM (SELECT  MIN(id) as id ,ms1, lig  FROM bulten GROUP BY ms1, lig) as bulten
INNER JOIN spor on bulten.ms1=spor.ms1 AND bulten.lig=spor.lig
group by bulten.id
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d277a/5

Comment: In addition, can we calculate how many matches have been won and how many matches have been lost?

Comment: can we do 1 win 1 los 50%

Comment: yes of course if it doesn't fit in a1 query make a subquery and join it

Comment: can you make a small example result 2-1,1-1 - explode and 1 win 1 draw %50 win 
I tried many queries without success.

Comment: you need first to have a chek function if the result is a win or a draw, i will take later a look if i find a quick solutin

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX(spor.sonuc, '-', 1) as one,SUBSTRING_INDEX(spor.sonuc, '-', -1)as two 
I'm exploding results like if(one>two)  I guess I need to do something like, but I always make the wrong query.

Comment: 100/count(spor.sonuc)*? 
here you have to multiply by the winner

Comment: You can do something like this to get win and draw, if you need cpunt add it to the subquery so that you have all the number to get your procentage see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d277a/34  but next time ask a new question